# Attach CSS with hook_block_view

Tags: theming, blocks

So I've attached CSS with this code to my custom block:

```
function expressweb_newsletter_block_view($delta='') {
  $block = array();

  switch($delta) {
    case 'newsletter_popup_and_icon' :
      $block['content'] = array(
        '#markup' => expressweb_newsletter_block_content(),
        '#attached' => array(
          'css' => array(
            drupal_get_path('module', 'expressweb_newsletter') . '/css/newsletter.css',
          ),
        ),
      );
    break;
  }
  return $block;
}
```

I've cleard cache and I don't have CSS attached to my block traditional way (by @import or link tag). Alghough there is a reference to newsletter.css file but in jQuery code which starts with 'jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings...'. But this doesn't work. Anyone know why? Besides, what is this code for?

Comment: I strongly discourage attaching CSS per block. Add them to module's info file, and use proper classes / IDs to make them only affect elements you need. Way easier to properly cache them this way.

Comment: Did you try using `$block['subject'] = NULL;`? Also, is the block being shown?

Comment: @kiamlaluno yes, the block is visible. I don't think title might be a reason. If it's not set it's NULL by default.

Comment: @Mołot that's what I did, I've attached css by stylesheets[all][] = css/newsletter.css and it behaves the same way as by #attached property. Weired.

Comment: I don't understand. You say attached css but code have jQuery. What do you want in this block?

Comment: @MrD I am not sure what you mean. I don't see jQuery code in the question code.

Comment: So can you see file with url yousite.com/sites/all/modules/[customs]/expressweb_newsletter/css/newsletter.css if you paste in address browser.
Note: if your modules in folder customs url need customs. If not don't need.

Comment: @MrD here is the screenshot with jquery part that is always added by drupal http://goo.gl/r6I9Es As you can see there is a newsletter css file (I've changed the name in the meantime), but there's no any link tag or import of this file above.

Comment: @kiamlaluno look at the commen above

Comment: I' m afraid that your file path css not correct. Can you try paste link http://localhost:8080/sites/all/modules/expressweb_newsletter/css/newsletter.css  in your address brower. If correct, content your file css is show. And i think your name module is not  "expressweb_newsletter". Are you sure that?